# For $R$-modules M, is $M\cong R^{\oplus n}\otimes_RM\cong M^{\oplus n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I wanted to explicitly give a bilinear map $R^{\oplus n}\times M\longrightarrow M^{\oplus n}$ when trying to prove that $R^{\oplus n}\otimes_RM\cong M^{\oplus n}$ and ended up with $(r_1,...,r_n,m)\mapsto ((\prod_{i=1}^nr_i)m,...,(\prod_{i=1}^nr_i)m)$ which seems to work in showing that every bilinear map to some $R$-module P : $R^{\oplus n}\times M\longrightarrow P$ factors through $M^{\oplus n}$.

But I think the same works for $R^{\oplus n}\times M\longrightarrow M$, $(r_1,...,r_n,m)\mapsto (\prod_{i=1}^nr_i)m$. So is this true or did I do a mistake?

I'm in a commutative ring $R$ with identity.

Edit: I probably should have made clear that I am trying to find a map that together with $M^{\oplus n}$ satisfies the universal property for the tensor product, and am not trying to give an isomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

The map you wrote is not an isomorphism. It is instead a map that arguably parametrizes (though not uniquely) *all* multiples of the **diagonal** map $M\rightarrow M^{\oplus n}$ (where the multiple, depending on an element $(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ of $R^{\oplus n}$, is $\prod_ir_i$). This is why, as you observe, you could make a similar argument for $R^{\oplus n}\times M \rightarrow M$.

Instead, what you want is the map $(r_1,\ldots,r_n,m) \mapsto (r_1m,\ldots,r_nm)$. You can check that this induces the isomorphism $R^{\oplus n}\otimes M \rightarrow M^{\oplus n}$ that you want. If you know about the distributive property of the tensor product, you can also deduce this same result by noting the following:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
R^{\oplus n}\otimes M & = & (R \oplus \cdots \oplus R)\otimes M\\
& \cong & (R\otimes M)\oplus \cdots \oplus (R\otimes M)\\
& \cong & M\oplus \cdots \oplus M\\
& = & M^{\oplus n}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Sorry I didn't make this clear in my opening post: I didn't intend to give an isomorphism, but wanted to find a map that together with $M^{\oplus n}$, satisfies the universal property for the tensor product of $R^{\oplus n}$ and M. When I thought I had found such a map, I didn't see why the map in my second paragraph wouldn't work for doing the analogous thing with $M$. If the map(s) I gave in the opening post do not fulfill the universal property, I would be interested in knowing why. Because then clearly I don't understand something yet and made a mistake in my 'proof'.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to show that if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $R$-modules (commutative $R$, for simplicity), then
$$
(A\oplus B)\otimes_R C\cong (A\otimes_R C)\oplus (B\otimes_R C)
$$
The bilinear map $(A\oplus B)\times C$ is
$$
((a,b),c)\mapsto (a\otimes c,b\otimes c)
$$
and it's quite easy to show that this satisfies the universal property.

By induction, we get the isomorphism
$$
(A_1\oplus\dots\oplus A_n)\otimes_R C\cong
(A_1\otimes_R C)\oplus\dots\oplus(A_n\otimes_R C)
$$

In your case,
$$
R^{\oplus n}\otimes_R M\cong(R\otimes_R M)^{\oplus n}
$$
and you're done recalling that $R\otimes_R M\cong M$.

If you want the “explicit” bilinear map, it is indeed
$$
\varphi\colon((r_1,\dots,r_n),m)\mapsto (r_1m,\dots r_nm)
$$

Suppose you have a bilinear map $f\colon R^{\oplus n}\times M\to P$; define $f_i\colon M\to P$ by $f_i(m)=f(e_i,m)$, where $e_i$ is the usual basis element of $R^{\oplus n}$. Now define $g\colon M^{\oplus n}\to P$ by
$$
g(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n)=f_1(m_1)+f_2(m_2)+\dots+f_n(m_n)
$$
Now check that $g\circ\varphi=f$.

---

Note that the map $R^{\oplus n}\times M\to M^{\oplus n}$ defined by
$$
((r_1,\dots,r_n),m)\mapsto 
\bigl(r_1r_2\dots r_n m,r_1r_2\dots r_n m,\dots,
r_1r_2\dots r_n m\bigr)
$$
is not bilinear (take $r_i=1+1$ and look).

The map $R^{\oplus n}\times M\to M$ defined by
$$
((r_1,\dots,r_n),m)\mapsto r_1r_2\dots r_nm
$$
is bilinear, but it fails to have the required universal property. Just think to the case $M=R$ and $n=2$: you would end up with $R^2\cong R$, which is not possible for commutative rings.

Comment: Concerning $(r_1,...,r_n,m)\mapsto (r_1m,...,r_nm)$, I don't understand how this gives me a well-defined map $g:M^{\oplus n}\longrightarrow P$ for any bilinear $f:R^{\oplus n}\times M\longrightarrow P$ as is required by the universal property. I set $g(r_1m,...,r_nm):=f(r_1,...,r_n,m)$ and want to show this is well-defined. So given $(r_1m,...,r_nm)=(r'_1m',...,r'_nm')$ I get $g(r_1m,...,r_nm)=f(r_1,...,r_n,m)=(\prod_{i=1}^nr_i)f(1,...,1,m)=f(1,...,1,(\prod_{i=1}^nr_i)m$ and $g(r'_1m',...,r'_nm')=f(1,...,1,(\prod_{i=1}^n r'_i)m')$, but why are the last components equal to each other?

Comment: I don't know what causes the formatting error in the above comment, it works fine if I use the code in a normal post. It's supposed to say $\prod_{i=1}^nr_i$

Comment: @see It's easy: the map you're trying to define is not bilinear, mine is. 

Comment: And the well-definedness of the factor-map?

Comment: @see I added some comments.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now why my maps don't work, but I still don't see how yours gives me a well defined map $g:M^{\oplus n}\longrightarrow P$ for any bilinear $f$ such as in my comment above. Is it clear what I am asking there? I want to show that the implicit definition $g(r_1m,...,r_nm):=f(r_1,...,r_n,m)$ gives a well-defined map, which I am trying to prove in the above comment but fail to accomplish. Can you help me with that, too?

Comment: @see Added; do the necessary check.

Comment: Sorry if this starts to get annoying for you, but now you explicitly gave the map, skipping the need to prove well-definedness, which I'm ok with. But this way how do you know $g$ is the only map that $f$ factors through?

Comment: @see Just prove it!